# launch Kubernetes job yaml from python API

Tags: python, kubernetes

I would like to launch a Kubernetes job yaml when I call a python API endpoint.
As I have Yaml file, I do not like to implement everything in python. What is the best approach?

1. should I call something like subprocess and execute a script like "`kubectl -n $k8s_namespace apply -f kubernetes_job.yml`" or any other way?
2. This job will download some large files and do some parsing, therefore it will take some time to get it done(say 2-3 min). is it bad to wait for the API response? if so what would be the alternative?

Comment: Why do you have to wait for the API response? your job will run as [Job Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) and will once the process is complete, it should be marked as `Complete`.

Comment: I'd definitely use a [Kubernetes client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/) over shelling out to `kubectl`.  I'm guessing you'll probably need to make some modifications to each separate Job and doing this on native Python objects will be easier and safer than modifying the YAML.

Comment: (Architecturally, also consider using a queueing system like RabbitMQ in combination with a long-running worker Deployment.  This can work independently of Kubernetes so it will be easier to develop and test, and it saves several difficulties around API permissions and managing the Jobs' lifecycles.)